# Azure WCF https 404 error

Tags: jquery, wcf, azure, https

**EDIT**
If I try to hit the web service endpoint of /dowork WITHOUT https, I still get an error, but it recognizes the valid endpoint. How do I enable HTTPS?

I have a WCF service that will eventually primarily recieve AJAX calls to manage state based on user bahavior.

I can't get back anything, currently, can you see where I went wrong?
(site/core.svc/dowork fails in both the browser and ajax)

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface Icore
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/dowork",
        BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped,
        ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml)]
    string DoWork();
}

[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class core : Icore
{
    public string DoWork()
    {
        return "hullo";
    }
}

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="4.0"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding></webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="Fusion.core" behaviorConfiguration="Fusion.CoreBehavior" >
        <endpoint contract="Fusion.Icore" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" address="" />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Fusion.CoreBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Are you connecting to https endpoint? Have you configured transport mode security in your <webHttpBinding>? Alternatively if you hit  http endpoint do you see that working?

Comment: I've tried meddling with that, but I get the same effect. I can go straight to core.svc just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're saying that "site/core.svc/dowork fails in ... the browser", which means that you're using HTTP GET to access the service. However, your contract uses [WebInvoke], which enables HTTP POST. Try changing [WebInvoke] to [WebGet] and see if it changes anything in the browser.

Comment: Sadly, it does not :( I agree with your note that this is wrong, but I think I would expect something other than a 404 error.

Comment: Actually, I'm pretty sure it's a 404 if it's a method mismatch. If it's not that, the next thing I can think of is 'security mode="Transport"' as commenter Praburaj pointed out (see http://taciturndiscourse.com/services/ssl-for-webhttpbinding/ ). You said you've tried "meddling with that", but can you actually edit your question to reflect these two fixes (WebInvoke->WebGet and transport security) so that we'll be able to see whether there are any issues in the "meddling"?